# slide show function need it to not start automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

Slideshow like this one

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2.2/chennighan/RapidlyPrototypeJavaScript/tree/master/lesson3/

How do i get it to stop going through the slides automatically?

```
<div class="carouselContainer">
```

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/1200/300" alt="image 1">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      Some Caption 1 text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/300" alt="image 2">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      Different Caption 2 text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the interval parameter in your javascript to stop it for going through the slides, here is an example :

```js
$(function() {
   $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: false
   });
});
```